# Java Error "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mslinks/ShellLink"

Tags: java, shortcut

I'm attempting to use ShellLink (Found at https://github.com/DmitriiShamrikov/mslinks/releases) to create shortcuts for some .exe files I'm moving around in my coding

```
public static void createShortcut(String folder, String system) throws IOException
{
    //Folder is where the .exe is. Linking directly to the .exe not the folder it's in
    //system is the desktop of the user's computer. I've tried both linking it to the folder and a .lnk file. 
    ShellLink.createLink(folder, system); 
    //ShellLink mslinks.ShellLink.createLink(String target, String linkpath)
}
```

Error

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mslinks/ShellLink

Error points to

```
createShortcut(Shortcut+"\\UniversalDesktop.exe", "C:\\Users\\" + Username + "\\Desktop\\" + selectedSystem + ".lnk");
```

Perhaps there is a better way to create shortcuts via Java programming? Note the .JAR for ShellLink is in my JRE System Library using `import mslinks.ShellLink;`. I'm at a loss of what is causing the error to appear

Comment: Just because you import it does not mean it is loaded when you run your program. There should be a way to add the jar to your classpath. Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Eclipse. Newest version with Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the JRE in Modulepath instead of Classpath. This caused the error